Лицензирование - что я должен включить в проект, использующий библиотеки с лицензиями MIT и LGPL
У меня есть небольшой модуль на python без лицензии. Он использует библиотеку pynput под лицензией LGPL и библиотеку playsound под лицензией MIT.
Мой проект не содержит исходного кода ни одной из библиотек, он просто использует их как зависимости в setup.py и main.py
Я указал ссылки на проекты и авторов в README и на Вики
Собственно, должен ли я еще что-то указать?

Ничего. Эти лицензии не накладывают ограничения на использование, в отличие от GPL. Только на производные работы.

Скорее всего даже указывать ничего не надо - всё необходимое подтянется автоматически в момент установки зависимостей (хотя будет нелишним для верности перепроверить, что авторы библиотек сами не накосячили и всё действительно подтягивается)
